# How to change the text size on the selected item in the Android Spinner?

Tags: android

How can I change the spinner selected item's text size?
[image]

I would like to increase the "English" Text size to show

Comment: Dear All, I have solved this question.
THank you.
The solution is 
ArrayAdapter<Long> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Long>(this, R.layout.spinner_textview_layout);

R.layout.spinner_textview_layout is a custom textview layout xml

Comment: if you have answered the question, you should put the answer below so that other people looking for help on this can immediately see it.